# If X is poly-time reducible to Y and X is in P, then Y is in P

Tags: complexity-theory, np, p-vs-np

The answer I found on the Internet is false. But my argument is that if I know that X is poly-time reducible to Y, which means I can use Y as a sub-routine to solve X, i.e., if I have a blackbox of Y that gives an answer to X and I am getting the answer in polynomial time (since X is in P), then the blackbox of Y must be giving an answer in polynomial time also.

Comment: When looking at oracles we almost always assume they run in constant time, so the blackbox of Y functions using magic and returns an answer in $O(1)$ time.

Answer (score 1):

When we say that X is polytime reducible to Y, it means that Y is at least as hard as X or that X is no harder than Y. The hardness of X does not affect the hardness of Y since Y is at least as hard as X; it can be even harder (may be NP or NP-complete) than X. Therefore, if X is in P, then it is not necessary that Y is also in P.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument is wrong.  There is no guarantee that there exists a blackbox that runs in polynomial time.

If I had \$10, I could buy you a coffee.  But that doesn't imply that I have \$10.

Answer (score 0):

The only time guarantee you get from "$X$ is polytime reducible to $Y$" is that the time required to form $X$ into an input for the $Y$-subroutine is polynomially-bounded in $|X|$.

If $Y$ were also in $\mathbf{P}$ then, complete-problems from complexity classes $\mathcal{C} \supsetneq \mathbf{P}$ would lie in $\mathbf{P}$, i.e., $\mathcal{C} = \mathbf{P}$. For instance, $\mathbf{P} = \mathbf{NP}$, $\mathbf{P} = \mathbf{EXP}$, and even $\mathbf{P} = \mathbf{R}$, clearly contradicting several hierarchical theorems.